# xpath - how to find the second checkbox?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this HTML

```
<ol>
  <li id="topic_roles_input">
    <fieldset class="choices">
      <input id="topic_roles_none" name="topic[role_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
      <ol class="choices-group">
        <li class="choice">
          <label for="topic_role_ids_107">
            <input id="topic_role_ids_107" name="topic[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="107" />Language Therapist
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <label for="topic_role_ids_106">
            <input id="topic_role_ids_106" name="topic[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="106" />Speech Therapist
          </label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I can select the first checkbox with:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"][1])
```

But I can't select the second with:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"][2])
```

How can I select the second checkbox, avoiding using the 106 / 107 id's (this is being used for repeated tests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `()`:

```
(//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"])[2]
```

Honestly your 1<sup>st</sup> as well as 2<sup>nd</sup> XPath select both checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

**This is one of the most FAQ about XPath**.

**Remember**: The XPath operator `[]` has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator.

The solution, as always when the default priority is to be overriden, is to use brackets:

**Use**:

```
    (//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]
```

**and**:

```
    (//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]
```

**And of course, you can also get the same results using:**

```
    (//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]
```

**and**:

```
    (//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no ID and you want to identify it based on the value rather than the nth position/order:

```
//input[@name='topic[role_ids][]' and @value='107']
```